# Alter Search Products per Page in WooCommerce Front End

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the following snippet to limit the number of products in search results on my website from 10 to only 8.

However, I noticed that it's also limiting the number of products shown via WP Admin Dashboard > Products > All Products to 8 if you use the filter. When you use the filter, it also only shows 8 products even if the filter has more than 8 products.

Is there a way to use this snippet only in search results in the front end and not in the WP Admin area?

```
function myprefix_search_posts_per_page($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '8' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','myprefix_search_posts_per_page', 20 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is correct. You will just need to add the `is_admin()` control to make sure the query is executed only in the frontend.

Also you should add the `is_main_query()` control to make sure it is the main query.

Finally, the `posts_per_page` parameter is an integer and not a string.

```
// change the number of search results per page
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_search_posts_per_page', 20, 1 );
function myprefix_search_posts_per_page( $query ) {
   // only in the frontend
   if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      if ( $query->is_search() ) {
         $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
      }
   }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it in your active theme's functions.php.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_product_query` to change `posts_per_page`. check the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'myprefix_search_posts_per_page', 999 );
function myprefix_search_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '8' );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't limit the search results on the shop to 8. I still see the default 10.